# Set values on ionic checkbox and save the values in storage - Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, checkbox, storage, ionic4

I am trying to make a TV Show Tracking application, with the help of checkbox I want the user to mark what episodes he/she watched. And I want with SQLite storage to save the checkboxes value and load them when the user opens the modal of that show.

With the functions I have, when I click a certain checkbox that episode is added to the array selected, let's say I add 3 episodes as watched and by mistake, I uncheck one of the three episodes, all of them are deleted from the array selected. I want to fix that, and also also to be able to save the "watched" episodes in the storage and get their values(watched-checked, not watched-unchecked) when the user opens the modal of that show.

The data that the API returns per season episodes it looks like this: 
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9nfz.png)

HTML:

```
<button ion-button color="dark" (click)="checkAll()">Mark all as watched</button>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let episodes of seasonepisodes; let i = index;">
    <ion-thumbnail style="width: 150px; height: 100px;" slot="start">
      <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300{{episodes.still_path}}">
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <ion-card-subtitle>Episode {{i+1}}:
      <br>
      {{episodes.name}}
      <br>
      {{episodes.air_date}}
    </ion-card-subtitle>
    <ion-checkbox slot="end" color="dark" (ionChange)="selectEpisode(episodes)" 
    [(ngModel)]="episodes.checked"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

TS:

```
seasonepisodes = null;
this.seasonepisodes = ((this.seasondetails || {}).episodes); (this gets only the episodes in particular season - it returns an array of objects(see Picture 1)

selected: any = [];

 checkAll(){
   for(let i =0; i <= this.seasonepisodes.length; i++) {
      this.seasonepisodes[i].checked = true;
   }
   console.log(this.seasonepisodes);
 }

  selectEpisode(data){
    if(data.checked == true) {
      this.selected.push(data);
    } else {
     let newArray = this.selected.filter(function(el) {
       return el.testID !== data.testID;
    });
     this.selected = newArray;
   }
   console.log(this.selected);
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Cool, but where is your question?

Comment: Sorry, my bad.
I added my question

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so there are currently two questions.

**Uncheck not working correctly**

The first one is, why all your entries in the `selected` array are deleted when you uncheck one checkbox. This seems to happen because you are filtering the wrong property.

```
selectEpisode(data){
  if(data.checked == true) {
    this.selected.push(data);
  } else {
    // You were checking for 'testID' which does not exist (as per Picture1 you provided)
    this.selected = this.selected.filter(el => el.id !== data.id);
  }
  console.log(this.selected);
}
```

**Saving the checked array to Storage**

This one doesn't really have one correct solution. The simpliest would be to save the array after each `selectEpisode()` call and load it on `ngOnInit()` from storage.

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  selected:any = [];

  constructor(
    private storage: Storage,
  ) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    const selectedStringified = await this.storage.get('selected');
    if (selectedStringified) {
        this.selected = JSON.parse(selectedStringified);
        console.log(this.selected);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.seasonepisodes));

        this.seasonepisodes = this.seasonepisodes.map(episode =>  
          this.selected.some(({id}) => episode.id === id) // if episode is in selected array 
            ? {...episode, checked: true} // Return it as a new object and check it
            : episode // else return it untouched
        )
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.seasonepisodes));
    }
  }

  checkAll(){
    this.seasonepisodes = this.seasonepisodes.map(episode => ({...episode, checked: true}));
    this.storage.set('selected', JSON.stringify(this.selected));
  }

  selectEpisode(data){
    this.selected = data.checked
      ? this.selected.some(selected => selected.id === data.id) 
        ? this.selected // do nothing if already present
        : [...this.selected, data]
      : this.selected.filter(el => el.id !== data.id);

    this.storage.set('selected', JSON.stringify(this.selected));
  }
}
```

Here a working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8mc3si).

Comment: Uncheck not working correctly - this is fixed.


With the storage - it saves the episodes but it doesn't show them on the checkbox(it's always unchecked). And it saves duplicates if i save Season 1 Episode 1 and close the modal, then open the modal and save Season 1 Episode 1 again in the array selected it would be  two elements(same episode saved twice - duplicate).

Comment: Sure, I just tried to outline what you have to do. The detailed implementation is something you will have to do yourself :)

Comment: Yes i understand that and i appreciate your help. I'm trying to figure it out - am i supposed to add a value on the check-box from the selected[i].checked so it can read the value? Thanks

Comment: Currently the loaded episodes are only written to the selected array in my example. Of course you have to mark all corresponding items in seasonepisodes as checked as well, as that is what you are iterating over. I'll expand on that in my answer.

Comment: I implemented the code you provided, what should i change in the HTML in order to get the value of the checkbox per episode? Thanks

Comment: Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: You won't need to change anything in the HTML. I updated my answer and added a working Stackblitz :)

Comment: It works great! One little thing - every time i open the modal of a ceratin season the episodes that are marked as watched are pushed to the storage again(it doesn't affect the checkbox value, but in storage there are duplicates of the same episode id(i checked this with a variable that reads the 'selected' storage length). 
For ex. If 5 episodes are marked as watched of a certain season with every opening of the modal it duplicates 10,15,20(episodes watched). I think in selectEpisode() should be an if statement that checks if that episode.id is already added to the storage. Correct? Thanks

Comment: This effect is happening because the `(ionChange)` triggers on all checked checkboxes. The `selectEpisode(data)` should be changed to only add the checked values if they are not already present.